# SQL: use Update together with Select and Insert for insert data without creating new records ? It's possible? Alternatives?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Using Insert and Select, through a cursor.executescript, I copy the data of a column of a table into a new table. Everything works correctly. Use SQLite.

[image]

The problem, however, is that "new" row of records are created (the last red colored row in the picture). Instead I would like to insert (copy) the data in the column of the already existing records, so all in the same row. I think i need UPLOAD and not Insert, but I don't know how (using Upload) to copy the data of a column of a table into a new table. For example, I would like to have the data "1" in all records from 1 to 20, and not in row 21 (row 21 must not exist). How can I do? Can you help me with the code? Thanks

```
cursor.executescript("""
    INSERT INTO ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato (ID_Campionato) #new table in photo
    SELECT ID_Campionato FROM ARCHIVIO_Campionati #old/other table
    WHERE Nome_Campionato='Serie A'; #column name of old/other table
    """)
con.commit()
```

**UPDATE: For a more precise question, I add the two sql tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE "ARCHIVIO_Campionati" (
    "ID_Campionato" INTEGER, #example: 1
    "Nome_Campionato"   INTEGER, #example: Serie A
    PRIMARY KEY("ID_Campionato" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato" (
    "ID_Sq" INTEGER,
    "Nome_Squadra"  TEXT,
    "ID_Campionato" INTEGER,
);
```

[image]

Comment: *The problem, however, is that "new" row of records are created (the last red colored row in the picture).* Are you sure that this is a row in a table, ans not a placeholder for new row created by your client software? Does `SELECT Id_sq FROM tablename ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1` returns 1613 or 1612?

Comment: could you send a picture that includes the "Nome_Campionato" column?

Comment: MySql is not the same as SQLite. Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @amiralisabzehparvar  Added in the question. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: There's no "UPLOAD" in SQL, the language, and nothing in what you posted demonstrates any problem. The query run successfully and inserted the single column you specified (ID_Camptionato) for the single matching row. What did you expect?

Comment: Are you trying to *set* `ID_Campionato` to a specific value? That's the job of `UPDATE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you inserted these 20 rows in `ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato`, you have to update the table and not insert new rows:

```
UPDATE ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato 
SET ID_Campionato = (
  SELECT ID_Campionato 
  FROM ARCHIVIO_Campionati
  WHERE Nome_Campionato='Serie A'
)
WHERE ID_Campionato IS NULL;
```

The `WHERE` clause is not really needed because all rows (in the current state of the table) have NULL in the column `ID_Campionato` but it will be needed in subsequent calls to the same query for a different value (say for 'Serie B' rows).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'll let you know later. I'm not home/house now. Thanks again

Comment: You pointed out WHERE ID_Campionato IS NULL and explained to me that I need the next Serie B. Thanks. I hadn't thought about it yet. I tried to insert your sql code, but it gives me a syntax error about WHERE ID_Campionato IS NULL. I am getting sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error. How can I solve? Can you edit your answer? Thanks

Comment: @heovan1999 the code is syntactically correct as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2c86dac3590a7a7655defde89d22b3b5 There must be a problem with your Python code.

Comment: Then it will be my problem because of the brackets or quotes. I am attaching the link of my syntax via your link site. What am I doing wrong? Thanks https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bbfcbe600c8f3f1e0fdf4c5283b26553

Comment: @heovan1999 Remove `;` before `WHERE`

Comment: I thank you. Rate both your response and that of the kind @ Panagiotis Kanavos. You both helped me. But I assign the solved question with your answer, because you also made me think about the NULL question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to set the championship field for all teams? Editing/updating data is the job of UPDATE.

Try

```
UPDATE ARCHIVIO_Squadre_Campionato
SET 
    ID_Campionato= (SELECT ID_Sq
                    FROM ARCHIVIO_Campionati
                    WHERE Nome_Campionato = 'Serie A');
```

It's often a lot easier to get answers if you explain what you want to do, not how you think it should be done

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'll let you know later. I'm not home/house now. Thanks again

Comment: I thank you for the answer. I vote you. You've been kind. Unfortunately, I can only assign one answer as the resolution of the question. I assign to forpas because he also pointed out the NULL issue, but still yours are 2 excellent answers and I thank you both very much